# Paypal Express checkout - not getting billing agreement ID

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to test reference transaction with Paypal Expresscheckout billing agreement id. But I don't get the BAID at all.
Here are the calls I'm making:

STEP 1: setExpresschecout call:

---

```
Request 
    Endpoint URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    HTTP method: POST
------------------------------------------------------------
POST data:
USER=insert_merchant_user_name_here
&PWD=insert_merchant_password_here
&SIGNATURE=insert_merchant_signature_value_here
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&VERSION=93
&PAYMENTACTION=SALE     # type of payment
&AMT=19.95              # amount of transaction
&CURRENCYCODE=USD       # currency of transaction
&RETURNURL=<return_url>  # URL of your payment confirmation page
&CANCELURL= <cancel_url>  # URL redirect if customer cancels payment
&L_BILLINGTYPE0=MerchantInitiatedBilling

-------------------
Response
----------------------
token=EC-7NH28597U8423791A 
-----------------------
```

It's reirecting me to Paypal for login and after clicking on 'Agree and Pay' button, redirecting me back to my site with token and payerID. As I don't need to store the customer details, I'm skipping GetExpresschecout call and directly calling doExpressCheckoutPayment with token and PayedID.

STEP2 : doExpresschecoutpayment

```
USER=insert_merchant_user_name_here
&PWD=insert_merchant_password_here
&SIGNATURE=insert_merchant_signature_value_here
&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment
&VERSION=93
&PAYMENTACTION=SALE     # type of payment
&AMT=19.95              # amount of transaction
&CURRENCYCODE=USD       # currency of transaction
&TOKEN=token_value
&PAYERID=payer_id_received
```

Here is the response. But it doesn't have the BILLING agreement id.

```
{"map":{"PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE":"None","PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT":"0.00","PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID":"KLQ6JKXB6DPZ6","TRANSACTIONID":"96C270379E2177052","PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE":"expresscheckout","AMT":"11.20","PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT":"0.62","CORRELATIONID":"fa14c423b7813","SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED":"false","TAXAMT":"0.00","PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE":"USD","PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID":"96C270379E2177052","PENDINGREASON":"None","PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE":"instant","VERSION":"98.0","PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON":"None","FEEAMT":"0.62","ACK":"Success","TRANSACTIONTYPE":"expresscheckout","TOKEN":"EC-7NH28597U8423791A","PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE":"0","BUILD":"5956203","PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME":"2013-05-12T12:55:48Z","PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY":"Eligible","INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED":"false","ORDERTIME":"2013-05-12T12:55:48Z","PAYMENTSTATUS":"Completed","PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT":"11.20","PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS":"Completed","REASONCODE":"None","PAYMENTTYPE":"instant","PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK":"Success","PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE":"ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible","SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT":"false","TIMESTAMP":"2013-05-12T12:55:48Z","PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY":"Eligible","CURRENCYCODE":"USD"}}
```

FYI..paymentaction is set to SALE as I need to capture the payment.

Any suggestions on what went wrong?

Thanks,
Punya

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run [CreateBillingAgreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateBillingAgreement_API_Operation_NVP/) API to get BAID.
This should be done after you get EC token from SetExpressCheckout API.

P.S Reference Transaction should be enabled on your account.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use "GetExpressCheckout" to see if they accepted the billing agreement or not.

You will also need to contact PayPal and specifically request that Billing Agreements and subsequently Reference Transactions are turned on for your merchant account.